# How to handle this error when use nodejs writing a chat server?

Tags: node.js

Here is the code:

```
var net = require('net');

var clientList = [];

var chatServer = net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.write("Hi\n");

    clientList.push(socket);

    socket.setEncoding('utf-8');
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
            clientList[i].write(data);
        };
        socket.end();
    });
}).listen(4000);
```

When i access `http://127.0.0.1:4000`, it give me some response:

```
Hi
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
```

But the program is crashed:
here is the output form the console:

```
C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop>node wy.js
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:289:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\wy.js:13:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

I can't fine the reason why there is an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a new client connects, you are storing the incoming socket in the `clientList` array, but then as soon as some data arrives on that socket, you are closing it with `socket.end()`, but not removing it from the array.  So, when you iterate through the array sending data to all the sockets in the `clientList` array, you have sockets in that list that are no longer open which generates an error.

The `Socket.writeAfterFIN` error means that you're trying to write to the socket after you've closed it.

That explains the error.  I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish so I'm not sure exactly what code to suggest to avoid this error.

Also, you can handle errors on a socket yourself (so your server won't stop) by adding:

```
socket.on('error', function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

And, you will also need to handle the close event if the client closes the socket:

```
socket.on('close', function() {
    // clean up references to this socket as it is no longer open
    // remove it from the `clientList` array and any other references we have to it
});
```